# Retina logo using PHP conditionals

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set a logo in an options panel for Wordpress, where there's the regular logo and the retina logo upload. I want it to work so if there's a retina logo uploaded, use that, but set to the regular logo size. If there is no retina logo but there is the regular logo, use that, otherwise use blog name. My issue is one of php conditionals that I can't quite seem to get right.

The following code produces two logos, the large and the small right now. The second line does properly produce a retinized logo. But I'm missing some kind of else statement? I did try php else in the second statement, but it produced errors.

```
<?php if (!empty($mandm['logo']['url'])) { ?> <div id="logo"><img src="<?php echo esc_url($mandm['logo']['url']); ?>" alt="<?php  bloginfo('name');?>" />
<?php if(!empty($mandm['retina-logo']['url'])) {?> <img src="<?php echo esc_url($mandm['retina-logo']['url']);?>" class="retina-logo" style="max-height:<?php echo $mandm['logo']['height'];?>px" /> <?php } ?></div> 
<?php } else { bloginfo('name'); } ?>
                        </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Retina.js](http://retinajs.com/)

Comment: Thanks :) I am using Retina.js, but for whatever reason it isn't working for the logo (because it is a separate upload through the options panel, maybe?)

Comment: It should work for any file technically, can you please elaborate the scenario?